# When is the next/first SDL Tridion Webinar of 2014?

Tags: discussion

I've not seen an announcement for the first SDL Tridion webinar in 2014, is there one scheduled for early January?

We've been showing off the Context Engine lately, we'd be happy to show a demo and talk about how cool it is :)